InvalidRequestError: The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated
I know the issue and i know i just need to change to the latest model of openai, however, i am not able to find out where to change it as my code does not have any value hard coded. below is how it looks like
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import streamlit as st
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from functools import lru_cache

@st.cache_resource  # Decorator to enable caching
def process_pdf(pdf_path):
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_path.name)
    text = ""
    page_number = 0
    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        print(f"reading page {page_number}")
        text += page.extract_text()
        page_number += 1
    return text

def main():
    load_dotenv('.env')
    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'sk-XXXX'

   
    st.header("How can I help you ")

    # Upload file
    pdfs = st.file_uploader("Step 1: Upload your PDF", type="pdf", accept_multiple_files=True)

    if len(pdfs) > 0:
        # Extract the text
        text = ""
        page_number = 0

        for pdf in pdfs: 
            pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)
            for page in pdf_reader.pages:
                print(f"reading page {page_number}")
                text += page.extract_text()
                page_number += 1

        # Split into chunks
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
                separator="\n",
                chunk_size=1000,
                chunk_overlap=20,
                length_function=len
            )

        chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)

        # Create embeddings
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        knowledge_base = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embeddings)

        prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
                            {context}
                            Question: {question}
                            Answer as a Safety expert in english:"""
        

        # Show user input
        user_question = st.text_input("Step 2: Ask a question")
        if user_question:
            docs = knowledge_base.similarity_search(user_question)
            tprompt = PromptTemplate(
                template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context","question"]
            )
            llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
            chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff",prompt=tprompt)
        
            with get_openai_callback() as cb:
              
            response=chain({"input_documents": docs, "question": user_question}, return_only_outputs=True)
              
             st.write(response)           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Please provide a full traceback as code-formatted text. As you said, the direct cause of the problem isn't your code; while we could run it to get the traceback ourselves, that information should be in the question body.

This question is similar to: OpenAI API error: "The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
